# Issues storing db results in JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I am storing results from my database into a JSONObject. I basically want the JSONObject to have personIds, and for each personId, have the list of all the ids of the cars the person purchased (car id), and the purchase date for each of these cars. I have the below code, but I am only getting results of one row. I am terrible with loops, clearly I am missing a point here. Please suggest what I could be doing wrong here, and why I am not getting back the results. Just to give an idea of the output, I have over 15 carIds for each personId, and each of these carIds have a purchase date.

```
public static JSONObject fetchPersonCarInfo(String person) throws SQLException
    {       
        JSONObject personCarInfoObj =  new JSONObject();
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;        
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase",username,password);
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT personId, carId, purchase_date FROM carz WHERE person = ?");
            statement.setString(1, person);
            rs = statement.executeQuery();          
            while(rs.next()) {                  
                if(personCarInfoObj.containsKey(rs.getString("personId")) {
                    personCarInfoObj.get(rs.getString("personId"));
                    personCarInfoObj.get(rs.getString("carId"));
                    personCarInfoObj.get(rs.getString("purchaseDate"));
                    } else {
                    personCarInfoObj = new JSONObject();
                    personCarInfoObj.put("personId",(new String(rs.getString("personId"))));
                    personCarInfoObj.put("deviceId",(new String(rs.getString("carId"))));
                    personCarInfoObj.put("deviceCheckinTime",(new Date(rs.getTimestamp("purchaseDate")).getTime())); //not sure how to get timestamp column
                }
            }           
        } finally{
            statement.close();
            rs.close();
            connection.close();
        }       
        return personCarInfoObj;
    }
```

Comment: I saw a similar question yesterday as well.

Comment: Yes, and you replied to it. Except we made some changes to the design, and are no longer using a map etc. Completely storing results in a JSONObject.

Comment: The answer given by Paul to my question didn't help, so I had to repost. Since its not a 100% duplicate of my original post, I am not calling it a duplicate post. Hope that's OK.

Comment: Thank you Max for the edit :)

Comment: Put a counter variable into the while loop and see if you loop over more than one row. If you do then I suspect the problem is that you override entries in the JSON object, so effectively you should always end up with the data of the last row in the JSON object. In that case you will need to modify your data structure in the JSON object to uniquely identify every entry (e.g. by row index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the comments that I have added to the code to understand the changes that I have made to the logic. Feel free to ask if you don't understand any part.

```
public static JSONObject fetchPersonCarInfo(String person) throws SQLException {

    JSONObject personCarInfoObj = new JSONObject();
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "username", "password");
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT personId, carId, purchaseDate FROM person WHERE person = ?");
        statement.setString(1, person);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        JSONArray carsArray = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            // lookup if we have an entry for personId already in personCarInfoObj
            if (personCarInfoObj.containsKey(rs.getString("personId"))) {
                // build a new object for car info                
                JSONObject personCarObj = new JSONObject();
                carsArray = (JSONArray) personCarInfoObj.get(rs.getString("personId"));
                personCarObj.put("deviceId", (new String(rs.getString("carId"))));
                personCarObj.put("deviceCheckinTime", new Date(rs.getTimestamp("purchaseDate").getTime())); //not sure how to get timestamp column
                // this will append new car info object to the array with key rs.getString("personId"))
                carsArray.add(personCarObj);
                personCarInfoObj.put(rs.getString("personId"), carsArray);
            } else {                    
                carsArray = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject personCarObj = new JSONObject();
                personCarObj.put("deviceId", (new String(rs.getString("carId"))));
                personCarObj.put("deviceCheckinTime", new Date(rs.getTimestamp("purchaseDate").getTime())); //not sure how to get timestamp column
                carsArray.add(personCarObj);
                // store all the cars purchased against that personId in personCarInfoObj
                personCarInfoObj.put(new String(rs.getString("personId")), carsArray);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        statement.close();            
        connection.close();
    }
    return personCarInfoObj;
}
```

Also, I would recommend to read about buiding JSON objects.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much buddy. Let me give it a try.

Comment: I am using import org.json.simple.JSONObject, and I don't have JSONObject.append. I see it in the API, but eclipse shows an error.  Does it work for you? Also, this is incorrect - new Date(rs.getTimestamp("purchaseDate")).getTime()). Eclipse is throwing an error on this line too.

Comment: What is column type and format of data stored in "purchaseDate" column?

Comment: purchaseDate is of datatype timestamp.

Comment: which api are you referring to? will a put work in place of append? - personCarInfoObj.put(rs.getString("personId"), personCarObj);

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Still no luck :( Doesn't print all the carIds, and their purchase date. Only prints 2 records :(

Comment: I have made the edits. Please have a look. It will work with org.json.simple api as well.

Comment: Glad I was of service :)